# Printing all permutations of strings that can be formed from phone number

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to print the possible words that can be formed from a phone number in php.  My general strategy is to map each digit to an array of possible characters.  I then iterate through each number, recursively calling the function to iterate over each possible character.

Here's what my code looks like so far, but it's not working out just yet.  Any syntax corrections I can make to get it to work?

```
$pad = array(
        array('0'), array('1'), array('abc'), array('def'), array('ghi'),
        array('jkl'), array('mno'), array('pqr'), array('stuv'), array('wxyz')    
);   

function convertNumberToAlpha($number, $next, $alpha){

    global $pad;
    for($i =0; $i<count($pad[$number[$next]][0]); $i++){
        $alpha[$next] = $pad[$next][0][$i];

        if($i<strlen($number) -1){
            convertNumberToAlpha($number, $next++, $alpha);
        }else{
            print_r($alpha);
        }
    }    
}


$alpha = array();
convertNumberToAlpha('22', 0, $alpha);
```

Comment: You might want to look at the source code of [Math_Combinatorics](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics/) which is a class for generating permutations and combinations.

Comment: Thanks Salman, I checked out the source but unfortunately I don't think I can apply any of the concepts in there to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do it. Fairly straight forward: it uses recursion, each level processes one character of input, a copy of current combination is built/passed at each recursive call, recursion stops at the level where last character of input is processed.

```
function alphaGenerator($input, &$output, $current = "") {
    static $lookup = array(
        1 => "1",    2 => "abc", 3 => "def",
        4 => "ghi",  5 => "jkl", 6 => "mno",
        7 => "pqrs", 8 => "tuv", 9 => "wxyz",
        0 => "0"
    );
    $digit = substr($input, 0, 1);          // e.g. "4"
    $other = substr($input, 1);             // e.g. "3556"
    $chars = str_split($lookup[$digit], 1); // e.g. "ghi"
    foreach ($chars as $char) {             // e.g. g, h, i
        if ($other === false) {             // base case
            $output[] = $current . $char;
        } else {                            // recursive case
            alphaGenerator($other, $output, $current . $char);
        }
    }
}
$output = array();
alphaGenerator("43556", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(243) {
  [0]=>string(5) "gdjjm"
  [1]=>string(5) "gdjjn"
  ...
  [133]=>string(5) "helln"
  [134]=>string(5) "hello"
  [135]=>string(5) "hfjjm"
  ...
  [241]=>string(5) "iflln"
  [242]=>string(5) "ifllo"
}
```

Comment: Works well, thanks for your work, I was scratching my head on this one, but I like your solution, it's really readable.  I would just declare the `$lookup` variable outside the function, and declare it as a global variable inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

How is this going to be used? This is not a job for a simple recursive algorithm such as what you have suggested, nor even an iterative approach. An average 10-digit number will yield 59,049 (3^10) possibilities, each of which will have to be evaluated against a dictionary if you want to determine actual words.

Many times, the best approach to this is to pre-compile a dictionary which maps 10-digit numbers to various words. Then, your look-up is a constant O(1) algorithm, just selecting by a 10 digit number which is mapped to an array of possible words.

In fact, pre-compiled dictionaries were the way that T9 worked, mapping dictionaries to trees with logarithmic look-up functions.

Comment: This is just a programming exercise I'm doing to better understand algorithms.  It's not supposed to be used in a real-world application.  In fact, I will only test it for numbers that are a few digits (says <=3 digits).  I understand your strategy of using a dictionary that does lookups in constant time, but for all intensive purposes my goal is just to apply recursion to the context of this problem to print out all possible string permutations.  I've changed the title of this to indicate that I'm trying to get all string permutations from a possible number.

Comment: @user784637 Right but if your goal is to better understand algorithms, you should investigate an approach like this - this is how something would be implemented in the real world and would be a much better algorithm practice problem.

Comment: @Colin: I'm sure those learning databases didn't start with views and stored procedures. Granted, getting to a point where you understand how and when to cut down iterations is the goal, but learning about a simple "Brute force" attack on a keypad isn't going to lead him/her down a path of poor algorithm practices.

Comment: @BradChristie I agree, but how many RDBMS do you see without support for an index? Because a database doesn't do much for you if it can't quickly and accurately store and retrieve data. I get what you're saying, though I don't agree with your analogy. In any case, no need to debate in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should read Norvigs article on writing a spellchecker in Python http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html . Although its a spellchecker and in python not php, it is the same concept around finding words with possible variations, might give u some good ideas.